# executing null values records

Tags: sql, null

i am trying to execute the records that have `TotalTime` `null` value from the table `NewTimeAttendance`...`TotalTime` datatype `nchar(10)`

```
select * from newtimeattendance where TotalTime =  'NULL'
```

....nothing

```
select * from newtimeattendance where TotalTime =  'null'
```

....nothing

```
select * from newtimeattendance where TotalTime =  'Null'
```

....nothing

```
select * from newtimeattendance where TotalTime =  null
```

....nothing

```
select * from newtimeattendance where TotalTime =  Null
```

....nothing

```
select * from newtimeattendance where TotalTime =  NULL
```

....nothing

when i select the whole table i can see that there is some `NULL` `TotalTime` values..!!

it is small select statment ..why doesn't it work ? is there a way (special way ) to execute the 'NULL' with  `nchar` type ?!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `IS NULL`

```
select * from newtimeattendance where TotalTime IS NULL
```

The MySQL doc has some good information on dealing with NULL values:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: Yeah. Basic SQL ;) Trinary logic - comparisons with NULL always fail, so you need a specific syntax.